# The system cannot find the file specified " return employeeDBContext.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList();"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, objectdatasource, aspxgridview

I am developing web application using vs 2017 ,EF v 6.0.1 with code first approach.On running the application I am getting error at employee repository class, return statement as "The system cannot find the file specified. return employeeDBContext.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList();".I am unable to upload the picture to explain clearly. And also I am using gridview with object datasource.
The below is my code along with connection strings.So, please Let me know where the problem is...

```
public class Employee
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeDBContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
  public class EmployeeRepository
{
    public List<Department> GetDepartments()
    {
        EmployeeDBContext employeeDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
        return employeeDBContext.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList();
    }
}
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="server=.;uid=sa;pwd=P@ssw0rd;database=Sample;" />
```

[The system cannot find the file specified "return employeeDBContext.Departments.ToList(); "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuGmH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is at web.config connectionstring. I replaced the following code

```
 <connectionStrings>
```

with the code

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=.\SQLSERVERR2;uid=sa;pwd=P@ssw0rd;database=Sample;" />
```

Changed the server name.

Thanks........